# Migrating from creating your own websites to WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am a web developer, used to creating sites with PHP, MySQL, CSS, etc. I have been thinking of migrating some of my sites into WordPress but I would need to be able to access my own MySQL database (preferably separate from the WordPress database), and creating forms and tables in PHP from that data.

Does anyone know of any WordPress help sites which are aimed at migrating from create-your-own and accessing PHP and MySQL. There is plenty of help about designing your own themes, plug-ins, etc, but not so easy to find sites for existing web designers.

Comment: WordPress is written in PHP so you will be able to use all PHP functionality within. Off course this will also make you able to access a separate MySQL database using PDO or whatever. Just create your own database connection class aside  WordPress its `Wpdb` class. You could also make your own tables inside the WordPress database. That way you can just use `Wpdb`

Answer (score 0):

The wpdb object can be used to access any database and query any table

```
$mydb = new wpdb('username','password','database','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($rows as $obj) :
   echo "<li>".$obj->Name."</li>";
endforeach;
echo "</ul>"
```